# Volume of parametric integral of convex set

Tags: convex-geometry, convex-analysis

Given $t,\mu>0$. I am interested in computing the volume of the $n$-dimesnional set

$$\int_{0}^{t}e^{A(t-\tau)}\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ \vdots\\ 0\\1\end{pmatrix}U\:{\rm{d}}\tau,$$
where the set $U$ is an 1D interval $[-\mu,\mu]$, and the $n\times n$ matrix

$$e^{At} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & t & \frac{t^{2}}{2!} & ... & \frac{t^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\\
0 & 1 & t & ... & \frac{t^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}\\
\vdots & & & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & ... & t\\
0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

is upper-triangular with all ones in the diagonal (this is exponential of the upper shift matrix). This problem appears in computing the reach set of the so-called n-dimensional integrator: $\dot{x} = Ax + e_{n}u$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, where the scalar $u\in U=[-\mu,\mu]$, and $A$ is the upper shift matrix, and $e_{n} = (0,0,...,0,1)$.

For $n=2$, the set looks like below, [see for example, p. 111, Example 3.6 here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~varaiya/Download/KurzhanskiVaraiya.pdf), and by direct calculation, the area is $\frac{2}{3}\mu^{2}t^{3}$ (using the equation for the two curves). I am interested in generalizing the volume computation in $n$-dimensions hoping that there could be a way to do this volume computation directly using convex analysis (instead of solving the ODE). I am looking for any ideas or references that can be relevant. [image]

Edit: The set-valued integral is formally defined as $\int_{0}^{t}F(\tau){\rm{d}}\tau = \lim_{\Delta\rightarrow 0}\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac{t}{\Delta}\rfloor}\Delta F(i\Delta)$, as in [here, see pg. 3 bottom](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/799e/6c972307f780e29b1f4dc951a3000c9b03fd.pdf)

Comment: Erm... How comes that the sum (or integral) of rectangles is not a rectangle? Or, in other words, what is your definition of the integral of a function whose values are convex bodies?

Comment: @fedja: I added the definition of the set-valued integral I am using, and a reference. I am thinking intuitively as: for each fixed $\tau$, we have a different rectangle. Perhaps this is flawed way to think?

Comment: But with this definition you always get a rectangle (if the sum is the Minkowski one), so where does your fancy shape come from? Am I missing something?

Comment: umm, I am confused now. The way I am getting this set is similar to the equation (6) in that reference (see the last but one equality involving the integral $\int e^{sA}U ds$). The next page top of that reference also describes why the integral may not be polyhedron even if set $U$ is a polyhedron. Perhaps I understood things completely wrong?

Comment: If you change the slopes of the sides, then you can get fancy curves indeed, but the sum of several rectangles with *aligned* sides is still a rectangle, isn't it?

Comment: I think I incorrectly phrased this question. I am rephrasing it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78704/discussion-between-abhishek-halder-and-fedja).